# OpenCV on Android: Canot create OpenGL context

Tags: android, opencv, opengl-es

I am trying to write a simple OpenCV example app on Android. Upon running Utils.bitmapToMat() method, I got this message in logcat:

> W/Adreno-EGL﹕ : EGL_BAD_CONFIG
>
> E/OpenCV_for_Tegra(9096): Canot create OpenGL context

Device: Nexus 10 on Lolipop
OpenCV version: 2.4.10
Android SDK target version: API-19

I am aware there is a known issue: http://code.opencv.org/issues/3372, but it should have been fixed long ago before my lib version 2.4.10.

Comment: Why the downvoting? I am anxious to know the answer. I have searched everywhere but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Having a similar issue on my Nexus 5.

Comment: @XiZhang have you found the solution? please share